# getLayoutInflater in a fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't seem to be able to access `layoutInflater` in the inner class for the `ArrayAdapter` `getView` fun. This code lives inside a `Fragment`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    layoutInflater // available here

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
}

private class MyAdapter(context: Context?, foo: ArrayList<Foo?>?) : ArrayAdapter<Foo?>(context!!, 0, items!!) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, container: ViewGroup): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        if (convertView == null) {
            layoutInflater // not available
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, container, false)
        }
        return convertView
    }
}
```

Comment: Inner classes in kotlin are "static" by default so they cannot access fields on parent class. Change your adapter declaration to `private inner class MyAdapter(...)`.

Comment: Pawel, is there something else I should know, I can't access `foo` declared as arraylist in constructor inside my fun

Comment: To access something in the constructor you need to define the values as `val` or `var`. Otherwise you cannot access them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line:

`convertView = LayoutInflater.from(container.context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, container, false)`

That way you can access the layout inflater.